# Getting Process ID/HWID from process by clicking on its' window

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen similar functions like this in screen-recording programs for an example. You click a window of a game for example, and the program focuses on the game.

So I want to do something similar,  but instead of recording the window I would like to get the Process ID/HWID/Window handle whatever from the process/program.

I hope that didn't get too messy for you guys to read...

I couldn't find anything when I was looking, but maybe it's possible somehow to see which window gets SetForeGround (obviously from when you click on it).

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Start with `WindowFromPoint`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Then `GetWindowThreadProcessId`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Lastly, `GetProcessIdOfThread`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You'd have to pinvoke these, I am not sure if the .NET library has them (the first one is not in the Base class library for sure).

Comment: +1 ...just don't forget mouse hook to know which point has to be passed to WindowFromPoint()!

Comment: Years ago I wrote a tiny screen grabbing application in C#, it shows how to register global hooks in C# so that you can progress further: http://ii.uni.wroc.pl/~wzychla/screengrab.html

Comment: GetWindowThreadProcessId already returns the process ID.  Don't use a mouse hook, a borderless window that displays a bitmap of a screenshot works better.